# How does searching a library with Planar Bridge work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I activate [Planar Bridge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPlanar%20Bridge%5d), does it mean I can search my library for *any* permanent card I want or do I have to search until I find the first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Search" is a keyword action that is explicitly defined in the rules. [Rule 701.17a](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Search) says

> To search for a card in a zone, look at **all cards in that zone** (even if it’s a hidden zone) and find a card that matches the given description.

In the case of Planar Bridge, you look at all of the cards in your library, choose a permanent card from among them, and put it onto the battlefield.

Comment: @dan And that is why it costs 8 mana. :D

Comment: Maybe worth noting that you don't have to find a card, because there is a restriction on the card type. If it said "search your library for a card", then you would have to choose a card, because it's public knowledge that there is at least 1 card. But in this case, it's possible that you have no permanents, so even if you find one, if it's one you don't want you don't have to choose it.

Comment: You don't even have to name it before you choose! You could be like "I definitely need Catacomb Slug here" and while you're sifting your cards for it find Grave Titan and think "maybe that's marginally better" and pick that.